# Trouble with upload component - Cakephp 2.0

Tags: image-uploading, cakephp-2.0

I was trying to incorporate file upload to my project  but whenever I access the a function in the controller  it gives me these warnings:

Warning (2): call_user_func_array(): First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'UploadComponent::initialize' was given [CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php, line 110]

Warning (2): call_user_func_array() [http://php.net/function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'UploadComponent::beforeRender' was given [CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php, line 110]

Warning (2): call_user_func_array() [http://php.net/function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'UploadComponent::shutdown' was given [CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php, line 110]

The upload component that I added works fine for my cake 1.3 version.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, by modifying the `Component`.
In cake php 2.0 all components must extend `Component`; failing to do this will trigger an exception.
For example:

```
class UploadComponent extends Component {
}
```